# grep -A <num> until a string

Tags: linux, bash, grep, fileparsing

assuming that we have a file containing the following:

```
chapter 1 blah blah
blah num blah num
num blah num blah
...
blah num
chapter 2 blah blah
```

and we want to grep this file so we take the lines
from `chapter 1 blah blah` to `blah num`
(the line before the next chapter).

The only things we know are

1. the stating string `chapter 1 blah blah`
2. somewhere after that there is another line starting with `chapter`

a dummy way to do this is

```
grep -A <num> -i "chapter 1" <file>
```

with large enough `<num>` so the whole chapter will be in it.

Comment: `grep -A 999 string1 | grep -B 999 string2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do with `awk`

```
awk '/chapter/ {f=0} /chapter 1/ {f=1} f' file
chapter 1 blah blah
blah num blah num
num blah num blah
...
blah num
```

It will print the line if flag `f` is true.
The `chapter 1` and next `chapter` to changes the flag.

---

You can use range with `awk` but its less flexible if you have other stuff to test.

```
awk '/chapter 1/,/chapter [^1]/ {if (!/chapter [^1]/) print}' file
chapter 1 blah blah
blah num blah num
num blah num blah
...
blah num
```

Comment: assuming that the only thing we know is "chapter 1" and that somewhere after that there is a string "chapter" ( we done know the number of it ) ?

Comment: @GiannisTzagarakis Updated post to use next chapter of any number to stop the output

Comment: just because I want to parse large files, awk seems to be the best solution.
It is faster than sed or grep. Thanks!

Comment: btw, do you know how can pass the number of chapter as a bash script variable? 
$num=1
awk '/chapter/ {f=0} /chapter $num/ {f=1} f' file

(awk -v n=$num  '/chapter/ {f=0} /chapter n/ {f=1} f' file) is not working

Comment: Here is how `awk -v test="$var" '/chapter/ {f=0} $0~"chapter "test {f=1} f'  file`.  Then just  set `var=2` and it will get chapter  `2`

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ne '/^chapter 1/,/^chapter/{/^chapter/d;p}' file
```

Comment: See OPs comment.  He does not know the number of the next chapter.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through grep itself also but you need to enable Perl-regexp parameter `P` and `z`.

```
$ grep -oPz '^chapter 1[\s\S]*?(?=\nchapter)' file
chapter 1 blah blah
blah num blah num
num blah num blah
...
blah num
```

`[\s\S]*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters until the line which has the string `chapter` at the start is reached.

From `man grep`

```
-z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
-P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
-o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```